# The COM add-ins decreased performance or caused Outlook to crash

Tags: outlook-addin

I have outlook com add-in which gives the below error when it loads in Outlook:-
"The COM add-ins decreased performance or caused Outlook to crash"
And disables the add-in.Is there a workaround to avoid or fix this issue?

Comment: You need to make sure your addins does nothing on startup.

Comment: It doesn't do anything on startup.

Comment: Then it can only be the .Net run-time loading.